# Arithmetic Job Test question

Tags: arithmetic

I'm taking a job test soon and was going through the sample test questions when I came across this question which may or may not be tricksy:

```
A full stack of paper weighs 10 pounds. How much does a stack of the 
same paper, whose dimensions are twice that of the first stack, weigh?
```

The wording is ambiguous, so I was hoping someone could help me out. Would it be 60 pounds (each dimension is doubled) or 20 pounds (one dimension is doubled)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weight is proportional to volume. Doubling each of the three dimensions increases the volume by a factor of $2\times 2 \times 2 = 2^3 = 8$. So the weight also increases by a factor of $8$. That means the new weight is $10\times8 = 80 \text{ lbs}$.